# Area enclosed by the function $f(x)=(x+3)(1-e^{x/5})$ and the $x$ axis between $-3$ and $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> What is the area enclosed by the function $f(x)=(x+3)(1-e^{x/5})$ and the $x$-axis between $-3$ and $1$ to $4$ decimal points??

I have integrated by parts to give $(x+3)(x-e^{x/5})-\left((x^2/2)-25e^{x/5}\right)$ but when I sub in the limits the answer does not make any sence after looking at a graph on the function

Many thanks

Comment: I have not checked your calculation. But there is a geometric mistake. For $x\gt 0$, the $x$-axis is **above** the curve, so for that part you need to integrate $-f(x)$. The integral "doesn't know" about area, and counts stuff below the $x$=axis as negative.

Answer (score 1):

From $-3<x<0$ the graph is above the $x$ axis and for $x>0$ the graph is below the $x$ axis.  So you will need to integrate like this:
$$\int\limits_{-3}^0 f(x)dx+\int\limits_0^1 -f(x)dx=\int\limits_{-3}^0 (x-xe^{x/5}+3-3e^{x/5})dx-\int\limits_0^1(x-xe^{x/5}+3-3e^{x/5})dx=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}-5xe^{x/5}+3x+10e^{x/5}\right]_{-3}^0-\left[\frac{x^2}{2}-5xe^{x/5}+3x+10e^{x/5}\right]_0^1=\frac{29}{2}-25e^{-3/5}-\frac72+10-5e^{1/5}\approx 1.1727$$

You can check the answer [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-3+to+0+of+%28x%2B3%29%281-e%5E%28x%2F5%29%29dx+-+integral+from+0+to+1+of+%28x%2B3%29%281-e%5E%28x%2F5%29%29dx)

Comment: Thank you I have applied that but it still does not seem correct and I don't know where im going wrong

Comment: What answer are you getting?